# How to validate smarty code with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, smarty

I need to validate an input field which can contain smarty code or e-mails. I do this with RegExp you can see the code below. The problem is that the e-mail validation removes all the slashes, while the closing tags of a smarty tag ({/foreach}) contain a slash. How can I solve this without removing the slash validation all together?

```
smarty: function(v) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\\{\\{[^\\{^\\}]+\\}\\}", "g");
    return regex.test(v);
},


emailOrSmarty: function(v) {
    if (this.smarty(v) !== true) {
        return this.email(v);
    }
    return true;
},

email: function(v) {
    var regex = new RegExp('^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~_.\\-+])+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-])+?\.)+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})+$');
    return regex.test(v);
},
```

Sample valid input

```
Example 1 (email):
example@website.com
Example 2 (smarty code):
{{foreach from=$find.users|filter:"male":$city' item='user'}}{{$user.mail}}{{/foreach}}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Do you want to validate an email in the smarty code? You might combine them. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4OvFTH/1)

Comment: I want the input field to contain valid smarty code and e-mails.

Comment: Why don't you remove the anchors `^` and `$` from the email pattern? Also note that `\\{\\{[^\\{^\\}]+\\}\\}` will match both structures but does take into account that there is an opening and a closing one if that should be the case.

Comment: And only an email address without other strings inside the smarty tags?

Comment: I made a mistake, it has to validate either an e-mail or the smartycode.

Comment: Do you mean like `emailOrSmarty: function (v) {
           return this.smarty(v) || this.email(v);
        },`

Comment: They user can insert either an e-mail adres or a smarty code(witch wil generate an e-mail adres). Both are valid inputs. Thank you for your trouble.

Comment: So you mean you want to match the second foreach where {{$user.mail}} is present like https://regex101.com/r/G0NdYS/1 See https://ideone.com/GR1dkL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern to match the smarty tags matches the opening and the closing tags. Not sure if that is intended.

If you want to validate if there is only an email address between the smarty tags, you might reuse the smarty pattern by matching the smarty pattern on the input string and then replace with an empty string. That will leave the email address.

Then you could use the email validation to verify the email.

Note that if you don't have escape all the `{}`. Your code might look like:

```
emailOrSmarty: function(v) {
    var smartyPattern  = /{{[^{}]+}}/g;
    return this.smarty(v) || this.email(v.replace(smartyPattern, ""))
}
```

I have added the same pattern again, but you might move it to another location to be able to reuse it.

If you want to test for either of them, you already have 2 verification functions. For your function you could use an or to return if either of them is `true`

```
emailOrSmarty: function (v) {
   return this.smarty(v) || this.email(v);
},
```

To test for the last smarty pattern with `{{$user.mail}}` you could add:

```
smartyMailPattern: function(v) {
    var pattern = /{{foreach[^{}]+}}{{\$user\.mail}}{{\/foreach}}/;
    return pattern.test(v);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit complicated; assuming that your email validation expression might be working fine, we'd just add the `foreach` part and check to see if it might work:

```
\{\{(.*?)\}\}\s*((?:[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.+-])+@(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9-])+?\.)+(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{2,})+)\s*\{\{\/(\1)\}\}
```

```js
const regex = /\{\{(.*?)\}\}\s*((?:[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.+-])+@(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9-])+?\.)+(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{2,})+)\s*\{\{\/(\1)\}\}/sg;
const str = `{{foreach}} mail-1@mail.com  {{/foreach}}
{{foreach}} mail-2@mail.com{{/foreach}}
{{foreach}} 
 mail-3@mail.com
{{/foreach}}
     `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/huYzmJ/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify/simplify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/huYzmJ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.